# My Javascript (used to re-order li's in a ul) doesnt work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, sorting

Help, here's my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// Get your list items
var items = $('ul.categories > li');

// The new index order for each item, first item is always numbered "0"
var order = [4,2,3,0,1];

// Map the existing items to their new positions        
var orderedItems = $.map(order, function(value) {
    return items.get(value);
});

// Clear the old list items and insert the newly ordered ones
$('ul.categories').empty().html(orderedItems);
});
</script>
```

This re-sorting works in all browsers except IE (which shows the list twice, so I suspect the `.empty()` doesnt work for some reason?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no need to call `empty()` before `html()` because any content within the element is completely replaced by `html()`.

Comment: Try `var $ul = $('ul.categories').empty();
$.each(orderedItems, function (_, li) {
    $ul.append(li);
})`

Comment: it looks fine to me in IE 9 http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Gk9w9/1/

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to empty it

Try

`$('ul.categories').html(orderedItems);`